# Square Connect API list payments does not return Mobile Staff ID

Tags: square-connect

I am using the Square Connect API to retrieve payments for a customer.  The Square Account has mobile staff setup.  The mobile staff ID determines the location of the sale.  I cannot access that in the API but is in the transactions CSV download.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out this limitation of the API. I've filed a feature request with the Square Connect engineering team.

As a suboptimal temporary solution, `Payment` objects returned by Connect endpoints do include a `creator_id` field, which corresponds to the staff member that processed the payment. Unfortunately, this ID does not match the ID specified by the merchant when adding the mobile staff member. If you can determine which `creator_id` maps to which mobile staff member, you can maintain a one-to-one mapping between them.